# Monitor biztalk server(biztalkmgmtdb) sql agent job failed on step 2 - Part1

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, sql-server-agent

In BizTalk Server 2013 R2 there's a job called Monitor BizTalk Server (BizTalkMgmtDb). 
This job checks the management and tracking databases and looks for any inconsistencies. 
If there are none then the job completes successfully. If there are inconsistencies, then the job fails.

The job failing is simply telling you that you must take care of the inconsistencies.

Error message:

> Executed as user: AD-ENT\DBA_LIFTS_SQL_SSDE_N. 67981 Orphaned DTA Service Instances in WUPWD02V0310\BTBAMUAT.BizTalkDTADb [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 50000).  The step failed.

[image: Monitor BizTal Server(BizTalkMgmtDb)]

```
    To find inconsistencies follow below procedure from SQL instance:

            Ø Step-1: Run below query from SQL instance 

            CREATE VIEW  [dbo].[bts_Monitor_Job_Issues]
            AS
                SELECT Inconsistancy.DBServer AS [Server Name], Inconsistancy.DBName AS  [Database  Name], Inconsistancy.nProblemCode AS [Problem Code], Issue.nvcProblemDescription AS [Description] FROM btsmon_Inconsistancies Inconsistancy INNER JOIN [dbo].[btsmon_Issues] Issue ON  Inconsistancy.nProblemCode = Issue.nProblemCode
            WHERE Inconsistancy.nCount > 0
            GO

            Ø Step-2: 

            USE [BizTalkMgmtDb]
            GO
             
            SELECT [Server Name]
                  ,[Database  Name]
                  ,[Problem Code]
                  ,[Description]
              FROM [dbo].[bts_Monitor_Job_Issues]
            GO
```

[image: Sql query]

To fix the issue simply run BizTalk Terminator also called BizTalk Health Monitor (BHM).
1.To fix "messages with refcount less than 0" error run Repair Refcounts for All Messages in BTS Terminator.
2.To fix "Orphaned DTA service instances" error Run repair Orphaned DTA service instances 
3.To fix "orphaned DTA service instances" error run DELETE Orphaned DTA Service Instance Expections in BTS Terminator.

Does any one know about how can removed biztalk messages from messageboxdb using sql query?

I can use biztalk terminators tool to remove those type of message from db but I wonder to know how it's possible using sql query please if you have answer that would be great!

Comment: You screenshots are rather hard to read.  In fact it looks like you photographed the screen rather than taking screenshots.   Can you please try copying the text off the error messages and putting that in the issue instead?

Comment: new screenshots added...

Comment: So what is wrong with using BizTalk Terminator / BizTalk Health Monitor?   It probably does run SQL statements to do the job.    You could verify that by running SQL profiles while running the terminations.  That would also give you the SQL statements it uses.

Comment: Yeah that's true to use BHM but every week sql agent job failed to execute on step 2 due to inconsistency.also I will try to run Sql profiles and find out what need to be done or how we can automate this type of inconsistency on biztalk server...thanks @Dijkgraaf

Comment: @DipenPatel: be wary of the fact that you need to stop host instances before terminating or running cleaning up procedures!

Comment: @PieterVandenheede ---thank you I will stoped HI before cleaning

Comment: How can we prevent Messages with refcount less than 0, without reference counts from BizTalkMsgBoxDb and Orphaned DTA service instances from BizTalkDTADb ? usually I need to run BHM quite frequently on my environment to clean up inconsistency so is there good practice to do regularly when ever SQL agent job failed.

Comment: @DipenPatel: you might want to move this to a different question alltogether.

Comment: @Pieter Vandenheede part2 has been posted.

Answer (score 1):

Using BizTalk Terminator or BizTalk Health Monitor will, most likely, fix your issues.

If you want to know more about the queries that are running in the background while fixing the issues, you could do as Dijkgraaf mentions in the comments: run something like SQL profiler to check which database queries are executed.
Although this might violate some EULA, you might even go as far as decompiling binaries to understand and see exactly what happens.

Note: be aware that you need to stop all BizTalk hosts instances before running these invasive queries.