# Monitor biztalk server(biztalkmgmtdb) SQL Server Agent job failed on step 2 - Part2

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Please go through: [Monitor biztalk server(biztalkmgmtdb) sql agent job failed on step 2 - Part1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330429/monitor-biztalk-serverbiztalkmgmtdb-sql-agent-job-failed-on-step-2-part1) for details how this question was born.

How can we prevent messages with refcount less than 0, without reference counts from BizTalkMsgBoxDb and Orphaned DTA service instances from BizTalkDTADb?

Usually I need to run BHM quite frequently on my environment to clean up inconsistency so is there good practice to do regularly when ever SQL Server Agent job failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are queries you can use in SQL that find if there are any orphaned messages in BizTalk.
One of these queries is this one:

```
select count(*) from [BizTalkDTAdb].[dbo].[dta_ServiceInstances] 
where dtEndTime is NULL and [uidServiceInstanceId] NOT IN 
  (SELECT [uidInstanceID] FROM [BizTalkMsgBoxDb].[dbo].[Instances] WITH (NOLOCK)
    UNION
    SELECT [StreamID]
    FROM [BizTalkMsgBoxDb].[dbo].[TrackingData] with (NOLOCK))
```

FYI: I found this query here: https://www.biztalkadmin.com/orphaned-messages-in-the-tracking-database/

It will list the count of the orphaned service instances. Remove the `COUNT` clause from your `SELECT` statement to get the list. This might get you an idea as to where they come from and how to perhaps change your implementation to limit the occurrence.

Note that a few orphaned instances are not a big deal for your BizTalk environment. Anything lower than 2000 can be more or less dismissed.

**Important**: do not run any cleanup query without stopping the BizTalk host instances or it may violate your support agreement.

Answer (score 1):

First, I never run Monitor BizTalk Server.  Preferring to run  BHM regularly.

If you are experiencing a build up of orphaned messages, then the jobs aren't what you should be looking at.  It's a app that allowing this to happen.

Comment: I'm not biztalk developer so I need to maintain environment as clean I can also I report that issue to Developers team to find out the solution, so if orphaned messages setting on BiztalkDTADb how we can get rid of them from DB ? Thank for response @johns